# How to differentiate potential form and passive voice for ru-verb?

Tags: verbs, conjugations

The method for conjugation is exactly the same with replacement of る　into られる

Comment: Thanks. I'm still not sure how to search similar question in stackexchange.

Comment: And btw, in the question you linked it is linked to yet another question with same question :D. Guess I'm not the only one confused by this.

Comment: I just put `potential passive` to the search box, and the question was the 9th result by relevance.

Comment: When I put potential passive there is so many questions regarding the same issue! Thank you for it and it is really a confusing issue ね?

Comment: It may be confusing to a learner, but not to native speakers; they use られる without knowing such a fact.  BTW English 'must' may be equally confusing; "You must be a good student" means different things depending on the context.